# JSON Parsing in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, angular

writing a service that returns an Array of JSON values. At the Service Recipient end, Traversing array is handled using a *ngFor. Each JSON is getting retrieved but I am not able to parse each value inside the JSON.
I Am trying to make a list of links, The Json Content is the name of the link and the route to which the link is supposed to be routing.

did try to access the values inside the JSON using the KeyValue pipe.
did try to make a custom pipe.
did try to call the value like "{{obj.Name}} {{obj.Route}}"
in which obj is the json object.

This is the structure of the JSON Array.

```
const LinkDirectory: ILinks[] =
[
{Name: 'Home', Route: '/home'},
{Name: 'Aboutus', Route: '/Aboutus'},
];
```

---

ILinks is an interface

```
export interface ILinks {
    Name: string;
    Route: string;
}
```

Angular Service that returns the directory.

```
@Injectable()
export class Directory{
    getLinks(): ILinks[]{
        return LinkDirectory;
    }
}
```

This is the Angular Component that receives the service.

```
export class LinksPopulate implements OnInit {
  LinkDirectory: ILinks[];
  constructor(private DirRetriver: Directory) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.LinkDirectory = this.DirRetriver.getLinks();
  }
}
```

---

Html Code with *ngFor

```
<div>
      <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let link of LinkDirectory">
      <a routerLink={{link.Route}}>{{link.Name}}</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

list of links with the specified name.
like an all products page in a shopping site.

Comment: what are you getting as result?

Comment: Please provide us with the actual JSON data instead of the format. And have to tried `JSON.parse()` to parse the returned data before storing it?

Comment: As i can see in your code you define `const LinkDirectory` are you defining that variable inside a function? The variable you use inside an *ngFor must be declared as instance field (component variable). Share a little more code about how you retrieve the *ngFor data, your HTML syntax seem fine.

Comment: @porgo I want to populate the page with a list of links. the LinkDirectory will be updated as soon as a page and routes are added. the result I am going for is a page with a list of links. consider a product showcase site of a product-oriented company with a page for each product. there is a link to view a list of all products, the list contains the name of the product which is clickable and when clicked will lead to the product page. I am trying to achieve that page which will list all the products.

Comment: @Dblaze47 pardon me but what do you mean by the actual JSON file. I haven't tired parsing it

Comment: @Simo I am defining LinkDirectory in an angular service which has a method to return the const LinkDirectory to the Service Recipient whoever calls the function. Following is the code of the component that is the service recipient and the one who uses the html i have written as its template.      ```export class LinksPopulate implements OnInit{
LinkDirectory: ILinks[];
 constructor(private DirRetriver: Directory){}
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.LinkDirectory = this.DirRetriver.getLinks();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post `Directory` service code too, it can be useful

Comment: @Simo yes, will update it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using a class LinkDirectory instead of an interface and removed the whole interface from the mix.